# What can I use for switching between fragments for android watch instead of viewpager?

Tags: java, android, wear-os, moto-360

I 'm doing left and right swiping operation for android watch with viewPager. I can switch between fragments using viewPager. But it sometimes sticks around, when I swipe to left current fragment (it works like onBackPressed). It brings from bottom the same fragment, althought I swipe left the current.

Therefore, I'm asking what can I use for switching between fragments for android watch instead of viewpager.

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: For watch main controller for all these things is GridViewPager, that is specially designed for wear devices
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.html

Comment: Your view pager is in fragment or activity?

Comment: it is in an activity KishanVaghela , I will try GridViewPager @MateuszPryczkowski , no, I haven't tried FragmentStatePagerAdapter usajnf . thank you all